# "New" Excel.Application vs Excel.Application

Tags: vba, excel, instance, excel.application

I am seeking clarification on the impact of "New" on the objects and the script.

My understanding is that if I need to perform actions on an excel document and the application is closed then I should use New Excel.Application.

If I keep this application active (through an object such as a Workbook for example) and later in the script I decide to open another workbook, should I still use New Excel.Application or would it be better to use Excel.Application then?

My concern lies in the fact that I am going to write a long script that will perform actions on at least 5 Workbooks. I will have to a switch from one Workbook to another and then come back to the former...

If each time the script creates a New Excel.Application, I may end up having quite a lot of them running and I am fearing that this mess would generate issues.

Is it more appropriate to write something like:

```
Dim NxlApp as New Excel.Application
Dim xlApp as Excel.Application

  NxlApp.Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\...\WorkbookA.xlsx"
  NxlApp.Visible = True

'Perform actions on WorkbookA (keep it open)


  Set ExcelApp = GetObject("", "Excel.Application.14")
  xlApp.Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\...\WorkbookB.xlsx"
  xlApp.Visible = True

'Perform actions on WorkbookB (keep it open)


'Go back to WorkbookA (using the xlApp variable this time)

  xlApp.Workbook("A.xlsx")...
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa141350%28v=office.10%29.aspx

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7zc73115(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: The OP has a good point... I've always noticed that the Microsoft Scripting Runtime requires a New keyword for FileScriptingObject but not so for other libraries. Why do some require New and other do not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The excel application can have several workbooks open at once so you don't need to instancing a new one. If you from inside excel you should not need to reference the application to open workbooks. You might wish to create several workbook instances e.g.

```
Dim wbWorkbookA As Workbook
Dim wbWorkbookB As Workbook

Set wbWorkbookA = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\...\WorkbookA.xlsx")
Set wbWorkbookB = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\...\WorkbookB.xlsx")
```

This will open the workbooks and give a reference so that you can manipulate them using your code.

Answer (score 6):

> I am going to write a long script that will perform actions on at
>   least 5 Workbooks

Good question, short answer is that you can open 5 workbooks in one Application object.

If you're in excel (else see below) then you already have an Excel.Application. You can then set each workbook to a different object or reference them by name:

```
dim wb1, wb2 as Excel.Workbook, wb3 as New Excel.Workbook 'blank is
same as Variant set wb1 = application.open("path/wb.xlsx") msgbox
wb1.name                  'ref by object msgbox
workbooks("wb.xlsx").name 'ref by name
```

> My understanding is that if I need to perform actions on an excel
>   document and the application is closed then I should use New
>   Excel.Application

If you're outside Excel (like in Access) then you may want to create an Excel.Application object, here are some tips:

```
Dim nXlApp as New Excel.Application
```

has the same effect as:

```
Dim xlApp as Excel.Application
Set xlApp = New Excel.Application             'Early Binding
Set xlApp = CreateObject(“Excel.Application”) 'Late Binding
```

Do not define (dim) inside a loop, however you can instantiate (Set) the same object as many times as you want. If you're using a global object (which is not recommended but sometimes handy) inside a control (button, etc) you may use something like this:

```
if xlApp is Nothing then set xlApp = CreateObject(“Excel.Application”)
```

When you're done don't forget to clean house!

```
wb1.Close False
set wb1 = Nothing 'do this once for each defined object, anything using New/Set
```

See also,

- [Difference between CreateObject("Excel.Application") .Workbooks.Open and just Workbooks.Open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044473/)
- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/288902 (GetObject and CreateObject behavior)

Comment: I needed the last part of cleaning. Thanks